# HDMI to CAT6 converter causing WIFI problems when transmitting

Tags: wireless-networking, hdmi, interference, cat6

looking for help.

I have the following setup:

Virgin v6 box > HDMI > Neoteck HDMI to CAT6 > CAT6 > Neoteck CAT6 to HDMI > TV

It works perfectly. The issue driving me mad is that it completely jams my WIFI signal whilst in use (The 2.4Ghz wifi works very poorly and the 5Ghz doesn't work at all). But as soon as I switch off the the Neoteck transmitter - the WIFI works perfectly again.

Note: due to wiring constraints the Neoteck transmitter, Virgin router and V6 box all need to be near each other...

Can anyone help or find a way round this issue?

Comment: Is the CAT6 shielded?  And is the cable connected to your router (i.e. on the network wireless uses)?  This sounds like radio interference, but want to rule out bandwidth problem.

Comment: Hi Steve - thanks for your response. I believe the CAT6 is shielded but in any event- from the point that it leaves the transmitter it runs on the outside of the house for around 10m and re-enters the house far away from the router. So I would be surprised if this was what was causing interference.  The cable is only directly connected to the neoteck devices. Would welcome any further thoughts in resolving this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All ok now. I managed to find a channel on the 5Ghz which doesn't seem to conflict. Thanks.

Comment: Your neighbours would still like you to improve the shielding, I'm sure.